# Does the Transcend JetDrive Lite 360 fit on iMac?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, external-disk, sd-card

[Transcend JetDrive 360](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-640) is a nice option to expand storage on mbp 15" Mid 2015.

I'm wondering if it can be used on iMac also, can someone confirm? Or somewhere else besides mbp 2015.

Comment: Please see this: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y

Comment: Start Here: [https://www.transcend-info.com/Support/contact_form](https://www.transcend-info.com/Support/contact_form)

Comment: The JetDrive Lite 360 fits perfectly in the SDXC slot of an iMac 21.5" Late 2012 (and I suspect every other Intel-based iMac after that, too). It works like a regular SD card.

Comment: The JetDrive Lite 360 also fits perfectly in the SDXC slot of an iMac 27" (5K, 2017) and works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

[This FAQ at Transcend](https://www.transcend-info.com/Support/FAQ-827) (which is linked to at the bottom of the link you provided) indicates indirectly that the only non-laptop mac compatible with the JetDrive Lite series is a Mac Mini.

I used one of these JetDrive devices several years ago on a 2nd gen MBA, and it is designed to lie flush with the edge of the laptop to prevent damage whilst in a bag or elsewhere. If I were going to try using one of these devices, I'd choose the one with the greatest length to make sure it seats correctly in the internal SD socket.

On the other hand, any of the high-performance SD cards now on the market will be much less of a pain to use with your iMac. Personally, I'd choose a SanDisk, Sony or Transcend SD card.

Remember that no matter how much improvement has been made in the quality of SD card fabrication and data reliability over the years, they are still more fragile than other data storage media, and are susceptible to data loss from static shock and other environmental conditions such as high magnetic fields, moisture and excessive heat.

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I'm a satisfied user of SanDisk, Sony and Transcend products, and have no financial or other ties with these companies.</sub>